# What is the best way to present "rate this app/game" with unity/c#?

Tags: unity, c#

I want to give my users a chance to rate my game at the Google Play Store. How can I achieve this on Unity/C#?

I would like users to be able to rate instantly inside the game window without being sent to the Google Play Store, but if I send them there I wanna get sure they come back to the app where they left. Just found solutions with Java but none on Unity/C#. Thanks.

Comment: I found this link [https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/unity](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/unity)
but I´m really curious if there are other ways, and how to send them to play store and get them back safely.
Nice to mention there is a time limit on how many times you can call this in app review. Sending directly to play store this doesn´t apply.